# How to include HTML template in a class?

Tags: php, include

I was told, that PHP5 doesn't allow include statement in classes?

Just verifying if this is right or wrong advice, and if right is this resolved in PHP7.

Comment: Mind lowering the CAPS? It's called shouting

Comment: Please don't SHOUT your questions. It's also not necessary to redundantly repeat tag information in your title. The tag system works extremely well and doesn't need help.  Instead, use that space to be more specific about what you're asking, so that it's useful to people in the future who are trying to find an answer to a similar question and are looking through a list of search results. The same can be said for your problem description - *Am having issues* is useless and isn't even a sentence. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't include files directly within the body of a class. It is of course possible to include files within a method.

Broken code:

```
class MyClass {
    include( 'myInclude.php' );
}
```

Working code:

```
class MyClass {
    public function __construct() {
        include( 'myInclude.php' );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll upvote, but I'd note that if you find yourself *doing* this, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: I suspect from the way the question is written that the author was attempting to include a file within the body of the class. It's worth clearing up the confusion but I'd certainly agree, neither example is something I'd like to see used.

Comment: @ceejayoz well, there is one specific usecase: http://chadminick.com/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html#sthash.TCmDzlWI.dpbs

Comment: @tereško Hence "probably". :-) Also, if you're making your own templating engine instead of using Twig/Blade/etc., that's another indication you might be doing something wrong!

Comment: @ceejayoz I need a "templating engine" for combining arrays and variables, what are returned in JSON responses for an API. Fight me! :D If you are talking about HTML templating, then - yes, I agree. Except, if you are actually learning how templating works.

Comment: "Fight me! :D"  Brave Sir Robin ran away... 